# Photo doesn't appear on cv with class moderncv

Tags: moderncv, fontawesome

I am making my CV using class `moderncv`. But each time that I try to compile, there is only a small black square (size depending on the thickness of the photo's border) instead of my photo.

[image: Here is what appears]

The photo is put in the right file and I've tried with and without the extension. But it still doesn't work. I've also noticed that the phone and address logos don't appear.

I thought this was because of the way I'm compiling: I'm using TeXnicCenter and always choose the `LateX>PS>PDF` compilation, but when I'm trying the `Latex>PDF` or `LateX>DVI>PDF` compilations, the PDF doesn't appear at all.

I've tried to compile with TeXmaker too, but I have the same problems.

Here is my code. Everything else is working, it's really just a problem with the photo and symbols for address and phone:

```
 \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 

 \moderncvtheme[black]{classic}

 \setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} 

 \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}    
 \usepackage[french]{babel}  
 \usepackage[top=1.1cm, bottom=1.1cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}

 \renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{28}{20}\mdseries\upshape}
 \firstname{\huge Me} 
 \familyname{\huge Nom} 
 \social[linkedin][lala]{/lala}
 \title{Student} 
 \address{rue XX,  XX}{XX} 
 \mobile{+33~XX}
 \phone{+33~XX} 

 \email{XX.XX@gmail.com} 
 \extrainfo{Femme, 23 ans} 
 \photo[70pt][0.5pt]{lala}  
 \quote{Canditure}{}
 \begin{document}
 \maketitle
 \section{Formation}
 \cventry{Août à Juillet}{DD}{Ecole}{}{}{Mécanique}
 \cventry{Septembre à Juillet}{Cycle}{Université }{}{}{Matériaux}
 \cventry{Septembre à Juin}{Tronc}{Université}{}{}{Cycle}
 \cventry{Juin}{Bac S}{Lycée}{}{}{Mention}
 \section{Expérience Professionnelle}
 \cventry{Février à Décembre}{Projet de Fin d'Etudes}{Ecole}{SP}{Fr}{lalala}
 \cventry{Septembre à Février}{Stage}{Entreprise}{Clermont-Ferrand}{France}{loulou}
 \cventry{Février 2010}{Stage Ouvrier}{Entreprise}{Paris}{France}{Découverte}

 \section{Compétences}

 \subsection{Langues}
 \cvlanguage{Anglais}{lu, parlé, écrit}{niveau}
 \cvlanguage{Portugais}{lu, écrit, parlé}{niveau}
 \cvlanguage{Espagnol}{lu, parlé, écrit}{niveau}
 \cvlanguage{Allemand}{notions}{niveau}
 \subsection{Informatique}
 \cvcomputer{Simulation numérique}{lala} {Conception}{lala}
 \cvcomputer{Web}{lala}{Langage}{lala}
 \cvcomputer{Autre}{lala}{}{}
 \section{Divers}
 \cvline{Associatif}{lala}
 \cvline{Loisirs}{lala}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Replacing "lala" with one of my images "images/rabbit.jpg"  worked fine.  Use unix style pathnames and include the extension.

Comment: I've just tried it, it did change the size of the square but I still can't see the picture. I've changed the photo and the extension to try, but it doesn't work. And I still can't compile using (Latex>PDF) directly or (Latex>DVI>PDF)

Comment: What sort of image is lala anyway?

Comment: It's a photo of myself on png or jpg formar (I've tried both formats). i need to put it on my resume to apply for a job.

Answer (score 3):

As I said, it worked fine for me:

```
\photo[70pt][0.5pt]{images/rabbit.jpg}
```

[image: photo test]

Comment: Hm well I don't understand then, because when I'm using Latex for another document, the pictures appear without any problem but when I'm using moderncv there is nothing. What do you use to compile? TeXnicCenter? Texmaker? Another?

Comment: TexnicCenter and MikTeX.  Is lala.jpg in the same folder as the tex file?

Comment: Yes it is and I'm also using TexnicCenter and MikTeX. I think that my problem comes from the fact that I'm compiling with (Latex>PS>PDF), so I'm trying to see why I'm getting a "fatal error" each time it's creating the PDF using (Latex>PDF) directly. I'm using Sumatra PDF now and I've tried to change the DDE command on the viewer but I still can not open the file.. I'll try to see here if there isn't another subject about that issue. Thanks for your help